# somethings wrong with my mysql query line

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this Laravel 4.2 Eloquent Query

```
$m[]     = Auth::user()->id;
foreach ($friends as $friend) {
    $m[] = $friend->added_user;
}

$news = NewsFeed::whereIN('user_id', $m )->take($limit)->skip($offset)->get();
```

Actual query:

```
$news = NewsFeed::whereIN('user_id', array( 'CUS_6367VkCX5i243656TwM3', 'CUS_G530t786S1GVwlcJ3Nw1', 'CUS_xks5oi3dy2C0sa02usD2' ) )->take(10)->skip(5)->get();
```

Database:
[image]

It should return something, Newsfeed Table has datas in it but
result is none, its empty.

What is wrong with my Laravel 4.2 Eloquent Query?

BUT WHEN I DO THIS:

```
$news = NewsFeed::whereIN('user_id', $m )->get();
```

it returns a result, without limit and skip.

Comment: post actual data from the table for these users ids

Comment: is it full result? only 3 records?

Comment: yes there are only 3 users register. you mean you want the newsfeed table?

Comment: i think the question should be  Convert this in to laravel eloquent ORM SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID IN (1,2) LIMIT 5, 5; 

NOTE: this query is invalid.

Comment: please thumbs up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `$m[] = $friend->added_user;` is where you go wrong

> dd($friend->added_user)

You will see in your array `$m` objects of users. However, in your query what's needed is the `user_id` of `added_user`.

In this case, you should modify as follows:

> $m[] = $friend->added_user()->first()->user_id; //it depends on what your `added_user` returns, if it returns an array, you should loop over it to get all ids or use `->lists('user_id')` to get an array of user_id

Hope it helps

Comment: i have updated my question, i added a database table of users

Comment: if i do this, it works $news = NewsFeed::whereIN('user_id', $m )->get();
but i wanted to use take and skip, limit the results.

Comment: i think what he is doing is like this: 
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID IN (1,2) LIMIT 5, 5;

which is wrong. its not working in http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_columns

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
$news = DB::select( DB::raw(" SELECT * FROM `news_feed` WHERE `user_id` IN ('CUS_6367VkCX5i243656TwM3', 'CUS_G530t786S1GVwlcJ3Nw1', 'CUS_xks5oi3dy2C0sa02usD2') LIMIT 5, 5 ") );
```